# table formatting without css

Tags: html, css

I have a table defined as

```
<table border="1" width="200px" height="auto">
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way that I can align the table at the center of the page,  apply background color to page without using css for any of these operations?

Comment: I have an editor which strips out the css , so I have no option but to apply the styles without using a css

Comment: @TJCrowder Perhaps corporate HTML email spam, accounting for old versions of Outlook. **Edit**: @user544079 That's a terrible reason!

Comment: @user: It even strips out `style` attributes? Yeesh. @Phrogz: +1 on your answer.

Comment: `width="200px"` should be `width="200"`

Comment: Why can't you just use notepad then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you are doing something horrible like HTML email:

```
<center><table bgcolor="#ff00ff"></table></center>
```

Comment: Why is it horrible and what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

```
<center>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td background="http://www.yourdomain.com/email/images/background.jpg" align="left">
            <!-- Stuff -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

- http://www.email-standards.org/
- http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/email-marketing-field-guide/
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/ultimate-guide-html-emails/

The background attribute was never valid on table or td.  Pretty sure the only thing the HTML 4 specification had background on was body.  But I vaguely recall that it worked elsewhere and I think table cells was elsewhere--whether it works in Outlook you'll just have to test.  bgcolor was valid all of those places...and is likely to work.